# UML проектирование на примере кода из С++

Tags: c++, ооп, книги, uml

Читаю о ООП, проектирование ПО и все что с ними связано. Так как UML это язык универсальный для ООП-языков программирования, то хотелось бы найти его конкретное применение в проектирование приложений под C++.

*Проще говоря*, мне нужны отрывки кода на примере некой модели или диаграмы на UML, что бы было проще понять. Например меня волнуют такие вопросы:

> Как реализуются такие связи между пакетами как import, access, use,
>   merge на примере кода в c++ и т.д.

**Сабж:** Быть может имеются какие-то книги по UML с примерами кода из C++? Или сайты, статьи, лекции.. что нибудь?

Comment: Если Вы сначала изучите язык, а потом уже будете заниматься всей это высокоуровневой галиматьей типа UML, то у Вас не будет появляться таких вопросов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос подругому, сейчас ваш вопрос не ставит какой-либо технической проблемы.

Comment: Проектировнаию учатся после того как приобретают опыт программирования. Если пытаться делать это ДО вам никакие объяснения не помогут. И да, ваш вопрос слишком не конкретный чтоб на него тут ответили.